# Getting a weird character when alerting escaped numbers

Tags: javascript

I find that when I escape numbers that start from 0 to 7 and alert them, I get a weird symbol:

```
alert( "\0" ); // or \1, \2, \3...\7
```

[image: Weird character]

This is only visible when I alert it, but document.write and console.log won't show it. Escaping numbers greater than 7 will appear fine. I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Why am I getting this weird character? Thanks.

Comment: Does not seem to happen in Chrome v22 on OS X.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm actually using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: `\0` is the `NUL` character which terminates strings in C, I believe it's similar for JS.

Comment: [This]( http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) may help

Comment: @Fabrício: Yes, but that does not explain `\1`, `\2`, etc

Comment: Invalid escape sequences are ignored by the parser and return the following digit normally, so `\1`-`\7` would be control characters I believe.

Comment: The real question is WHY you're escaping characters which aren't supposed to be escaped? There's absolutely no point to that except very specific cases such as fooling the DOM parser with a `<\/script>` in a local jQuery fallback such as HTML5 Boilerplate's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How string literals are parsed in general is described in [section 7.8.4](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4).

However, the behaviour you see is described in [Annex B.1.2](http://es5.github.com/#B.1.2). This section is about octal escape sequences in older ES versions, which still seems to be supported. The resulting character is defined as follows:

> - The CV of *OctalEscapeSequence :: OctalDigit [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]* is the character whose code unit value is the MV of the OctalDigit.
> - The CV of *OctalEscapeSequence :: ZeroToThree OctalDigit [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]* is the character whose code unit value is (8 times the MV of the *ZeroToThree*) plus the MV of the *OctalDigit*.
> - The CV of *OctalEscapeSequence :: FourToSeven OctalDigit* is the character whose code unit value is (8 times the MV of the *FourToSeven*) plus the MV of the *OctalDigit*.
> - The CV of *OctalEscapeSequence :: ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit* is the character whose code unit value is (64 (that is, 82) times the MV of the *ZeroToThree*) plus (8 times the MV of the first *OctalDigit*) plus the MV of the second *OctalDigit*.

`\x` (`\xx`, `\xxx`) is only interpreted as octal sequence if `x` is an octal digit, i.e. between `0` and `7`.

So, all the characters `\0` - `\7` are actually [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters). Higher values refer to other characters, for example `\101` is `A`.

I cannot tell you why `alert` is showing a strange character and the console does not show anything... that's probably an implementation detail.

---

**Fun fact:** Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.

**Fun fact #2:** `\0` is actually not an octal escape sequence and will still work in strict mode, since it has its own production rule (see [section 7.8.4](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4)). OTHA, `\00` is an octal sequence and will throw an error in strict mode.

Comment: Cool. I've known about this little quirk for a while, but I never got around to asking about it. Now when I do `"\1234567"`I get `S4567`. Also, `"\44" == "$"` :)

Comment: Yeah, only the first three digits are considered to be part of the escape sequence, and `\123` seems to be `S` :)

Comment: Another question: Why can I only see that character with `alert` and not `console.log`, `.write`, or with the HTML?

Comment: I don't know... presumably those characters are ignored in HTML  but `alert` uses the native interface to render text.

Comment: @user6607—it's related to how the host environment displays the string. If displayed in an HTML page, then HTML rendering rules are used. In an alert, the host environment's rules are used (same as why `<br>` is a line break in HTML but `\n` is required in an alert).